# CircleCI vs Bitbucket Go Build Issue

Tags: go, circleci, alpine-linux, bitbucket-cli

I'm running a `go build` command on a `golang:1.11-alpine` on two separate CI tools. As you can see the commands are exactly the same and the docker image is exactly the same.

For some reason, when I run the compiled executable on an `alpine:3.9` docker image, only the **bitbucket** runs.

For the Circle CI build, I get the following error:

> standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused “exec format error”

I was reading online that it might be an architecture issue so I did a `file <file>` in the terminal and it appears both were compiled the same way. Here is the response I received for both files (identical):

> cloud: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, stripped

### Circle CI

```
docker:
  - image: golang:1.11-alpine

steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      name: Build Go Server
      command: |
        apk add --no-cache git build-base
        export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
        export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
        go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint@v0.0.0-20190227174305-8f45f776aaf1
        go mod vendor
        golint -set_exit_status $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
        go test -short $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
        go build -ldflags="-s -w"
```

### Bitbucket CI

```
steps:
    - step: &step-test-and-build-go
            name: Test and Build Go Server
            image: golang:1.11-alpine
            script:
                - apk add --no-cache git build-base
                - export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
                - export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
                - go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint@v0.0.0-20190227174305-8f45f776aaf1
                - go mod vendor
                - golint -set_exit_status $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
                - go test -short $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
                - go build -ldflags="-s -w"
```

### Circle CI `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/root/project/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build122963699=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

### Bitbucket CI `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build179086021=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I have cross-posted this question [to the CircleCI forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/circleci-vs-bitbucket-go-build-issue/31898).

Comment: What does `go env` show on each platform?

Comment: @Peter I've updated my question to show this. They seem to be almost identical besides the `-fdebug-prefix-map`

Comment: Possibly related to the fact that alpine uses `musl`?

Comment: @Zyl maybe, but the curious part is why I'm getting different results on the same alpine image for different CI's.

Comment: Is there any platform/environment at all on which you can get the binary produced by the Circle CI build to run and does the one from Bitbucket run there as well? I know that's tapping in the dark but maybe it's a start.

Comment: What is the output from CircleCI for the steps that complete?  (e.g are we failing at "go get" or "golint")?

Comment: How do you get the compiled binary out of the build and running on the `alpine:3.9` image?

Comment: @koblas we aren't failing on CircleCI. I'm going to try to get a reproducible this weekend

Comment: @PabloLalloni I push it to a repo, run `alpine:3.9`, pull it down, and try to run it

Comment: It's not clear what command triggers the error. You're showing the error (exec format) and the CI script, but you're not showing what you do after the CI finishes (it's not even clear whether the CI finishes correctly or not). You should show the full CI log, and what exact command you're using that generates that error.

Comment: try `RUN mkdir /lib64 && ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in linux apline 3,8

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28065) might be related.

Setting `CGO_ENABLED=0` on alpine might solve it unless it is required by your build. The line to add could be like:
`export CGO_ENABLED=0`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is the problem because both already had it enabled and one works.

Comment: To clarify, disabling means setting 0 for CGO_ENABLED. To enable, value must be 1 which is the usual default. Go release plays a role and installation could be customized. This is why forcing 0 in CircleCI could solve it.

Answer (score -2):

> > GOMOD="/root/project/go.mod"

Well, taking the fact that there is exactly one difference between the two environments, I'd say your GOMOD value is the culprit.

> > Bitbucket CI go env
> >     GOMOD="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/go.mod"

As an aside, check your go version as well, modules did not run before golang 1.6 if I remember my gopher trivia correctly.

Comment: `GOMOD` is not read from the environment (so setting it will have no effect), it's additional information provided by `go env` and it's the absolute path to the go.mod of the main module.